# How could i get only the first line of an exception stack trace message in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I wan't to print the stack trace message for debug purposes, but i'm only want the first line because i'm interested on getting where the problem started.

Example:

```
at Solution.Models.Class.Method() in C:\Users\...\Models\Class.cs:line 1118 <-- i´m only interested in this
at Solution.Models.Class.AddSomething(Something _something) in C:\Users\...\Solution\Models\Class.cs:line 518
```

Comment: "*because it has the line of code that i'm interested in.*" - This will not always be the case unless your code throws the exception, I would suggest just using a good logging library and aggregator and be done with it

Comment: “i'm only interested in the first line because it has the line of code that i'm interested in”; a dubious tautology.

Comment: I'm also printing the full stack trace, but i need that only that because it's shows the line i need to care for other thing i'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var firstLine = originalMessage
    .Split(Environment.NewLine)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Where:

- `originalMessage` - the string that you want to get the information from;
- [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) - returns a string array of the substrings that are your `originalMessage` divided by the passed parameter `Environment.NewLine`;
- [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-5.0) - gets the newline string defined for this environment. `\r\n` for non-Unix platforms, or `\n` for Unix platforms;
- [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0) - returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found;

---

This is a Linq expression that will work on all platforms, whether it is Linux, Windows or Mac due to `Environment.NewLine` utilization instead of hardcoded `"\r\n"`. Also, by stacking Linq expressions one on each other you construct a certain pipeline that says:

1. I am taking a string;
2. Which I then split into substrings by a line separator;
3. And take the first substring from the result;

Answer (score 1):

You can just `substring` it until the new line:

```
string firstLine = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("\r\n"));
```

Comment: Using `string.Split` (and then `.First`) is probably clearer